# Not able to generate notification for Facebook through restfb

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

i want to send facebook notification to my friend through my app . i have used following notification api through restfb library

facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(vAccessTokenDetails.getVAccessToken());

String app_access_token = facebookClient.obtainAppAccessToken("485626xxxxxx614","d9428570ef5ae82609b6xxxxxxxb").getAccessToken();

publishMessageResponse = facebookClient.publish(post.getVFriendId()+"/notifications?access_token="+app_access_token, FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("template", post.getVMessage()), Parameter.with("href", "http://www.wiinkURL.com"));
                                    vPostId = publishMessageResponse.getId();

but i am getting  **com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#15) This method must be called with an app access_token**

Answer (score 1):

The FacebookClient object should be created using app_access_token instead of access_token.

```
FacbookClient facebookClientAppAccessToken = 
    new DefaultFacebookClient( app_access_token );
publishMessageResponse = facebookClientAppAccessToken.publish(..);
```